# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace _2pDina
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            void FirstLine(string katet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(katet + "\t");
            }

            void SecondLine(string katet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(katet + katet + "\t");
            }

            void ThirdLine(string katet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(katet + katet + katet + "\t");
            }
            void FourthLine(string katet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(katet + katet + katet + katet + "\t");
            }

            void FifthLine(string katet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(katet + katet + katet + katet + katet + "\t");
            }

            void SixthLine(string katet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(katet + katet + katet + katet + katet + katet + "\t");
            }

            {
                int i = 1;
                int n = 0;
                string katet = "+";

                Console.WriteLine("Введите кол-во прямоугольных треугольников: ");
                n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("\n");

                if (n != 0 && n <= 6)
                {
                    if (n == 1)
                    {
                        FirstLine(katet);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (n == 2)
                    {
                        for (i; i <= 2; i++)
                        {
                            FirstLine(katet);
                            i = 1;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;

                        for (i; i <= 2; i++)
                        {
                            SecondLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                    }
                    else if (n==3)
                    {
                        for (i; i <= 3; i++)
                        {
                            FirstLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 3; i++)
                        {
                            SecondLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 3; i++)
                        {
                            ThirdLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                    }
                    else if (n == 4)
                    {
                        for (i; i <= 4; i++)
                        {
                            FirstLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 4; i++)
                        {
                            SecondLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 4; i++)
                        {
                            ThirdLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 4; i++)
                        {
                            FourthLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                    }
                    else if (n == 5)
                    {
                        for (i; i <= 5; i++)
                        {
                            FirstLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 5; i++)
                        {
                            SecondLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 5; i++)
                        {
                            ThirdLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 5; i++)
                        {
                            FourthLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 5; i++)
                        {
                            FifthLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                    }
                    else if (n == 6)
                    {
                        for (i; i <= 6; i++)
                        {
                            FirstLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 6; i++)
                        {
                            SecondLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 6; i++)
                        {
                            ThirdLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 6; i++)
                        {
                            FourthLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 6; i++)
                        {
                            FifthLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                        for (i; i <= 6; i++)
                        {
                            SixthLine(katet);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        i = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error! Enter value from 1 to 6");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

в строчках с `for(i;........` ошибка в переменной i

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кто Вам такое показал - `for(i; ...`?

---

```
for (/*i*/; i <= 3; i++)
```

или

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
```

Comment: Я взял это из c++. Спасибо!

Comment: @foder. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.